# static object array

Tags: java

```
public class Array                                                               
{
    static String[] a = new String[] {"red", "green", "blue"};
    static Point[] p = new Point[] {new Point(1, 2), "3,4"};

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

    class Point
    {
        int x;
        int y;

        Point(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        Point(String s)
        {
            String[] a = s.split(",");
            x = a[0].parseInt();
            y = a[1].parseInt();
        }
    }
}
```

In the above program, the static `Point` array initialization fails, reporting error:

```
Array.java:4: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
    static Point[] p = new Point[] {new Point(1, 2), "3,4"};
```

But, the static `String` array succeeds. What's the difference between them?

I really need a static object array, because it's easy to refer to without instantiate the outer class.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to make `Point` a static nested class, like this:

```
static class Point {
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to do three things to make your code to work. I will explain them . First see the working version.

```
public class Array {
    static String[] a = new String[]{"red", "green", "blue"};
    static Point[] p = new Point[]{new Point(1, 2), new Point("3,4")};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

    static class Point {
        int x;
        int y;

        Point(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        Point(String s) {
            String[] a = s.split(",");
            x = Integer.parseInt(a[0]);
            y = Integer.parseInt(a[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

The following are the three changes you have to make.

**1. change `"3,4"` to `new Point("3,4")` or `new Point(3,4)`**

We know that an array can hold items of similar types. Here you are declaring an array named `p` of type `Point`. That means it can contain item of type `Point` only(or its subtypes). But the second element `"3,4"` is of type `String` and you have a mismatch. So you must specify either `new Point("3,4")` or `new Point(3,4)` to get items of type `Point`.

**2. You need to make your `Point` class `static`**

From [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html):

```
An instance of InnerClass can exist only within an instance of OuterClass 
and has direct access to the methods and fields of its enclosing instance.
```

Here your `Point` class is an inner class and it must have given access to all the members of `Array` class. For that, each object of `Point` class must associated to an object of `Array` class. But, the array `p` you are creating is in `static` context. So, you have to either make the `Point` class a `static` one or make the array `p` a non-static one.

**3. `parseInt` is not a method of `String` class**

`parseInt` is a static method of `Integer` class and not of `String` class. So you must call it like `Integer.parseInt(stringValue)`.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

`Point[]` must be array or `Point` `"3,4"` is not instance of `Point`
and make Point class static for this error

Answer (score 1):

Here is the explanation from the [Oracle Online Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

> **Inner Classes**
>
> As with instance methods and variables, an inner class is associated
>   with an instance of its enclosing class and has direct access to that
>   object's methods and fields. Also, because an inner class is
>   associated with an instance, it cannot define any static members
>   itself.
>
> Objects that are instances of an inner class exist within an instance
>   of the outer class. Consider the following classes:

```
class OuterClass {
    ...
    class InnerClass {
        ...
    }
}
```

> An instance of InnerClass can exist only within an instance of
>   OuterClass and has direct access to the methods and fields of its
>   enclosing instance.

Also it cannot be accessed from within static members of the enclosing type, as it requires a an instance to exist.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your `Point` class as static:

```
...
static class Point
{
    ...
}
```

It is needed because `Point` is an inner class (`String` is not).

However, `{new Point(1, 2), "3,4"};` is your next problem. I guess it should be `{new Point(1, 2), Point(3, 4)};`

Comment: Thanks. I want "3,4" to trigger the Point(String). It seems it's unable to do so.

Comment: `Point(String xy) { String [] tmp = xy.split(","); x = Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]); y = Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]); }`?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make Point Static nested class.

```
static class Point {

}
```

check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)